# DropDown selected value to be transfered in spring

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

From jsp i need to transfer the value selected in drop down when a user click on search button which is submitting the form.

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="firstVO" method="post"> 

    <form:select path="secondVO.status" 
    id="status" > 
    <form : option value="all" label="All" /> 
    <form : option value="new" label="New" /> 
    </form:select> 

    <input type="button" name="search" value="Search" onclick="filterData();" /> 

    </form:form> 

    function filterData(){ 

    document.forms[0].action    =   Path+"/filter.do"; 
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
    } 
    ------------------------------------------------- 

    public class FirstVO { 

    private SecondVO secondVO; 
    } 


    public class SecondVO { 

    private String status; 
    } 

    public class DPSController { 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/filter.do") 
    public ModelAndView filterDashboard(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute SecondVO secondVO) { 
    System.out.println("secondVO.getStatus:"+secondVO.getStatus()); 
    } 
    }
```

Note: DPSController is the action class which is printing the status selected value.

```
Any idea please?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model attribute is firstVO and not secondVO.  Changing the filterDashboard signature as shown below should work.

Change

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/filter.do") 
        public ModelAndView filterDashboard(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute SecondVO secondVO) { 
        System.out.println("secondVO.getStatus:"+secondVO.getStatus()); 
    }
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter.do") 
    public ModelAndView filterDashboard(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute FirstVO firstVO) { 
   System.out.println("firstVO.getSecondVO().getStatus:"+firstVO.getSecondVO().getStatus()); 
    }
```

Comment: This thing works correctly. Thanks. But if i add one text box in jsp page and access it in DPSController class than it is returning null. Ex: JSP:  <input name="psoNumber" id="psoNumber" type="text"  value="${secondVO.psoNumber}" />      public class SecondVO { 

    private String status; private String psoNumber;
    }             @RequestMapping(value = "/filter.do") 
    public ModelAndView filterDashboard(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute FirstVO firstVO) { 
   System.out.println("firstVO.getSecondVO().getStatus:"+firstVO.getSecondVO().getPsoNumber()); 
    }

Comment: Instead of <input> tag. Please try with the <form:input>, it will bind correctly.